# I Want To Get Random Element From Firebase's Cloud Storage and Show It On SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

When I simulated that code, it pops up error on the screen.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var array = [String]()
    @State private var item = "Start by tapping."
    func deneme() -> [String] {
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("testaArray").document("testDocument").getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:))
                let array = dataDescription.map(String.init(describing:)) as! [String]
                for items in array {
                    self.array.append(items)
                }
            }
        }
        return self.array
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.item = self.deneme().randomElement() ?? "Error"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error to explain the issue a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore db access is an async task.

You need to wait until callback is finished.

What happens is that in

`self.deneme().randomElement() ?? "Error"`

`deneme()` immediately returns self.array when db access is running in the background,

at this time self.array is empty, and `randomElement()` call returns nil, so you have "Error".

A solution:

`.onTapGesture {self.deneme()}`

`func deneme() {// ... in callback, self.item = array.randomElement() ?? "Error" }`